# How to Disable Port 0.0.0.0/0

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am recently facing some massive network attacks on my VPS server and I believe its possibly due to some of the ports being open. Specifically this port: 0.0.0.0/0

I would like to know how to disable this port. (I have ufw installed and working as well.)

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

So while you've asked how to disable this port, it seems you would be better aided with some reference material to better understand what you have asked.
To that end I suggest to start with reading about the following:

 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

 https://www.grc.com/port_0.htm

 https://blog.endace.com/2013/08/27/ddos-attacks-on-port-0-does-it-mean-what-you-think-it-does/

 Edit: Blocking ICMP traffic can cause various problems depending on how you do so, but [this](https://www.tecmint.com/block-ping-icmp-requests-to-linux/) describes how with iptables and UFW. I personally haven't worked much blocking ICMP on a VPS so I can't advise you there other than to say use caution.

Comment: I got this from my hosting company when I added a support ticket " it appears you have left several ports open to the world (0.0.0.0/0). Leaving ports open like this can leave your instance vulnerable to compromise and unwanted network activity in general. To avoid these types of vulnerabilities, we recommend locking down your instances.".

This is why I was trying to look for a method of blocking this traffic.

Could you provide me with the firewall command to disable ICMP traffic? I would like to see if it works.

Comment: Added to answer with an article that you can try.

Comment: 0.0.0.0/0 in the hosting company's ticket does not mean the ports you have open; it means *the world* expressed in terms of IPv4 addressing. Also, blocking all ICMP traffic will break a standard technique known as Path MTU Discovery (PMTUD for short), which will cause you problems with VPNs and cloud services, which may use a smaller-than-normal MTU value.